# Matlab: sorting files according to creation date

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a bunch of files in a directory which are not named in any order. So when I use dir function, I get them in some order. But I would like to read those files in the order of its datenum. Is there an option in dir or any other function which can achieve this task.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to convert the `date` field by `datenum`. Presupposing you already have the datenum, which is a field in the structure already returned by `dir`, i.e. if you use `files = dir()` then `files.datenum` is are the dates converted to double format. So to use them by date all you would need is:

```
[~,idx] = sort([files.datenum]);
```

Then the `idx` contains the values from oldest `files(idx(1))` to newest `files(idx(end))`. Use `'descend'` as an option in `sort()` if you want to edit the newest first.

Comment: You are right. But that was not the question provided by the OP. My answer only solves the problem he was directly addressing.

Comment: maybe true, for some reason I had a feeling the OP looks at all `files.name` the `dir` outputs...

Answer (score 2):

here's a way to sort it out:

```
files=dir;
valid_file_names= find(~[files.isdir]);
file_date=[files.datenum];
[~, ix]=sort(file_date)
ix=ix(ismember(ix,valid_file_names)); keep index of file names only

     % load...
     for n=1:numel(ix)
         c{n}=your_loading_function(files(ix(n)).name);
     end
```

Comment: Now it is sufficiently different, but I did notice that had you adjusted your post to include information that I provided. Maybe this was coincidental. No worries.

Comment: funny , when I started answering it, it was only me, then I added the folder names case and only then I saw the additional answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
list = dir('c:\*.*');
[r inx]=sort({list.date});
list = list(inx);
```